# Why does Scala 2.9.1 not realize NodeSeq is also GenTraversableOnce

Tags: scala

I keep getting this error:

```
[error]  found   : (scala.xml.NodeSeq, Int) => scala.xml.NodeSeq
[error]  required: (scala.xml.NodeSeq, Int) => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
[error]       { answers.zipWithIndex.flatMap(answerElem) }
[error]                                      ^
[error] one error found
```

`answers` is just a `List[NodeSeq]` and `answerElem` just checks the index and sets an attribute on an element. As you can see, its parameters are the right type, and `NodeSeq` says that it extends `GenTraversableOnce`.

Is there a hint I have to give it to help it compile?

Todd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you confirm if your function is of type `Function2[NodeSeq, Int, GenTraversableOnce[_]]` or `Function1[(NodeSeq, Int), GenTraversableOnce[_]]`? If it's the former, that could be your problem, because `zipWithIndex` produces tuples. The answer would then be:

```
answers.zipWithIndex.flatMap(answerElem.tupled)
```

I did an experiment with an un-tupled function and reproduced something like your problem, and fixed it with the above. Not the most helpful error message though...

Comment: The unhelpful error message is a bug, a regression in 2.9.1.  If that is the problem, in trunk the message is of the form "found: (A, B) => C, required: ((A, B)) => C."

Comment: That was it. I forgot that it was a tuple. Once I changed my function to expect a tuple, it all worked. And thanks, extempore, for telling me that the error message is a bug. I feel a little better.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is due to the compiler trying to **resolve two implicit CanBuildFrom** and an appropriate pair can not be found for both. Seperating zipWithIndex and flatMap seems to allow the compiler to resolve the CanBuildFrom for each correctly however.

```
{ val zip = answers.zipWithIndex; zip.flatMap(answerElem) }
```